# sorting algorithm getting an 'index out of range' error

Tags: python, python-3.x

A sorting algorithm in ascending order:

```
import random

num=[]
for x in range(10):
    #x=0
    ran=(random.randint(1,99))
    num.append(ran)
    #x+=1

print(num)

y=0


while y<11:
    y+=1
    if num[y]>num[y+1]:
        num[y],num[y+1]=num[y+1],num[y]
        
    else:
        continue
print( num)
```

The error is:

```
 line 17, in <module>
    if num[y]>num[y+1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: When `y == 9`, `y+1` will be out of range

Comment: this fixed it ,can you explain further

Comment: FYI (probably unrelated to the question you didn't ask... ): You can simplify the initialization to `num = [random.randint(1,99) for _ in range(10)]`.

Comment: Your list has 10 elements, so the only valid indexes are `0..9`

Comment: while y<10: <--

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that for some value of `y`, `y+1` is greater than the maximum index of `num`.

The maximum index of `num` is 9 because `range(10)` produces an array of length 10. However in your while loop y goes up to 10, which means `y+1` goes up to 11. You can make the error go away by replacing `y < 11` with `y < 9`.

However your algorithm doesn't work as is, because you only go through the array once. If you try it out with `[8, 6, 3]` you'll end up with `[6, 3, 8]`. Sorting by permutating adjacent elements is a valid method called [Bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#:%7E:text=Bubble%20sort%2C%20sometimes%20referred%20to,until%20the%20list%20is%20sorted.) but you have to go through the array multiple times, until there is no permutation left to do. That's why a bubble sort generally performs poorly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

because `num` has 10 elements which means indices have to be between `0` and `9` (all inclusive). In your `while`, `y` ends up exceeding `9`. You get this error when `y` is `9` as you attempt to make an access to an element with index `y + 1` (10).

By the way, even if you fix your `IndexError` your algorithm is not currently achieving what you want. One of the simplest ways is

```
import random

num = [random.randint(1, 99) for i in range(10)]

print(num)

for i in range(len(num)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(num)):
        if num[i] > num[j]:
            num[j], num[i] = num[i], num[j]

print(num)
```

Output

```
[62, 16, 16, 82, 69, 99, 83, 6, 41, 48]
[6, 16, 16, 41, 48, 62, 69, 82, 83, 99]
```